# Partially ordered set defined by two comparisons?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have a set of items, each of them with a grade and a price. On this set, a partial order is defined where x <= y if grade(x) <= grade(y) and price(x) <= price(y).

I have items like price(x) = 3 , grade(x) = 1  and price(y) = 2, grade(y) = 3. I don't understand how these should be ordered. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in a *partial* order, two objects don't necessarily have to be comparable; maybe $a\not\le b$ *and* $b\not\le a$!

That's what happens here. By definition, $x\le y$ iff $grade(x)\le grade(y)$ and $price(x)\le price(y)$. In the specific case you mention, the grade of $x$ is lower than the grade of $y$, but the price of $x$ is higher than the price of $y$; this means that $x$ and $y$ are not comparable.

---

On an abstract level, you're seeing a way to combine two partial orders to get a third. If $\le_1,\le_2$ are two different partial orderings on the same set $X$, then their *intersection* - $x\le_3 y$ iff $x\le_1y$ and $x\le_2 y$ - is also a partial ordering on $X$. You're looking at the intersection of the "price" and "grade" partial orderings. (And there are lots of other methods for building new partial orderings from old.)

Comment: Thank you so much! So when am asked for the max of some items, and any two of them are not comparable, does that mean there is no max among these?

Comment: @Tina Yes, if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable then their "maximum" doesn't make sense. Their *supremum*, however - the least thing bigger than each of them - might! E.g. for your $x$ and $y$, the supremum might be something with price 3 and grade 3. So be careful to check exactly what is being asked.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help :-)